# Symfony BinaryFileResponse forces file download when filename has an accent

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.8

I am trying to show an image directly in the browser with the help of BinaryFileResponse in a Symfony controller.

On our previous server, this code was working all fine:

```
 $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath, 200, [], true, null, true);
 $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-cache', true);
 $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('max-age', 0);
 $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('must-revalidate', true);
 $response->headers->addCacheControlDirective('no-store', true);

 return $response;
```

But since the migration on the new server, when the $filePath contains an accent (àéè, etc), it forces the image to download instead of just showing it.

Both servers have PHP 7.0.10 installed.

Am I missing a config or something? I can't find why it happens.

Any help is gretaly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found my problem.

Symfony could'nt get the filetype mime in path containing accents. To make it possible, I had to activate PHP extension php_fileinfo in Apache.